# Market-2001 software used in Gode and Sunder (1993)

Tags: experimental-economics

I am reading [Gode and Sunder (1993)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2138676). They study the allocative efficiency of markets using a double auction mechanism where both humans and zero-intelligence computer programs are present as buyers and sellers.

There they have used the "Market-2001" software to run their experiments involving both human participants and machine traders. I searched the term on Google but couldn't find any relevant link.

What is this software? Is it usable now? Are there other such softwares, newer ones? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Market 2001 is a piece of software Gode and Sunder wrote themselves for their work in Turbo Pascal. There is a description in

Gode, D. K., and Shyam Sunder. 1994. [Human and artificially intelligent traders in a
double auction market: Experimental evidence.](https://spinup-000d1a-wp-offload-media.s3.amazonaws.com/faculty/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2019/06/HumanArtifi.Intellige.Gode.S.1994.pdf) In K. Carley and M. Prietula, eds.,
*Computational Organization Theory*. Erlbaum.

There exists software by Mark E. McBride based on the work of Gode and Sunder that is available [here](http://www.memcbride.net/models/2014/7/11/zi-trading).